# pandas apply a list of api functions to many dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, types, apply

I want apply a list of [`pandas.api`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.api.types.pandas_dtype.html) functions to many dataframes and get their response.
My code:

```
panda_apis = [
pd.api.types.infer_dtype,
pd.api.types.is_bool_dtype,
pd.api.types.is_categorical_dtype,
pd.api.types.is_complex_dtype,
pd.api.types.is_datetime64_any_dtype,
pd.api.types.is_datetime64_dtype]

api_df = pd.DataFrame(data={'function':[i.__name__ for i in panda_apis]})
api_df.head()

    function
0   infer_dtype
1   is_bool_dtype
2   is_categorical_dtype
3   is_complex_dtype
4   is_datetime64_any_dtype

# Two example dataframes

df1 = 

               Datetime     value
0   2002-12-31 01:00:00     5077.0
1   2002-12-31 02:00:00     4939.0
2   2002-12-31 03:00:00     4885.0
3   2002-12-31 04:00:00     4857.0

df2 = 
              Datetime      value
0   2013-12-31 01:00:00     1861.0
1   2013-12-31 02:00:00     1835.0
2   2013-12-31 03:00:00     1841.0
3   2013-12-31 04:00:00     1872.0
4   2013-12-31 05:00:00     1934.0
df1 = df1.addprefix('df1_')
api_df[df1.columns] = api_df['function'].apply(lambda x: eval(x(df1)))
```

Present output:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Expected output:

```
api_df = 
    function                df1_Datetime  df1_value   df2_Datetime  df2_value
0   infer_dtype                  string     float  ....
1   is_bool_dtype                False      False  ..
2   is_categorical_dtype         False      False  ..
3   is_complex_dtype             False      False  .. 
4   is_datetime64_any_dtype      True       False  ..
```

Comment: Why `is_datetime64_any_dtype` should return `True` ? How do you define `df1` and `df2` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
lst = [df1.add_prefix("df1_"), df2.add_prefix("df2_")]

out = (
    api_df.join(
        pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([
            df.apply(f) for f in panda_apis]) for df in lst], axis=1)
    )
)
```

*NB : A DataFrame column can't have more than one [dtype](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/basics.html#dtypes)*.

Output :

```
print(out)

                  function df1_Datetime df1_value df2_Datetime df2_value
0              infer_dtype       string  floating       string  floating
1            is_bool_dtype        False     False        False     False
2     is_categorical_dtype        False     False        False     False
3         is_complex_dtype        False     False        False     False
4  is_datetime64_any_dtype        False     False        False     False
5      is_datetime64_dtype        False     False        False     False
```

With the `Datetime` *s* cast to `datetime64[ns]`, we get :

```
                  function df1_Datetime df1_value df2_Datetime df2_value
0              infer_dtype   datetime64  floating   datetime64  floating
1            is_bool_dtype        False     False        False     False
2     is_categorical_dtype        False     False        False     False
3         is_complex_dtype        False     False        False     False
4  is_datetime64_any_dtype         True     False         True     False
5      is_datetime64_dtype         True     False         True     False
```

Comment: Why am I doing it: because I have many datafames. But all of them will have a timestamp column. I don't know if all of them will have same name for timestamp column. I want to identify the column name by the dtype of that column. It is true. Presently the timestamp columns are object type, not timestamp  type. That is, one more challenge.